# tablegrob is returning code instead of a table

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I have a problem with tablegrob:

```
   require(gridExtra)
   require(grid)
   head(iris,5)
```

this produces the normal table. Now i want to use tableGrob to put it on the grid. so

```
 p4<- tableGrob(head(iris,5))
    p4
```

And tablegrob returns

```
TableGrob (6 x 6) "rowhead-fg": 72 grobs
    z     cells       name                 grob
1   1 (1-1,1-1) rowhead-fg text[GRID.text.3354]
2   2 (2-2,1-1) rowhead-fg text[GRID.text.3355]
3   3 (3-3,1-1) rowhead-fg text[GRID.text.3356]
4   4 (4-4,1-1) rowhead-fg text[GRID.text.3357]
5   5 (5-5,1-1) rowhead-fg text[GRID.tex
```

Anyone got any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Maybe `grid.draw(p4)` is what you need.